# Puppy frugal install Harddisk Grub Problem

Tags: grub

I tried to install Puppy Linux 5.2 on a Harddisk (IDE), since the BIOS does not allow USB boot.

As described [here](http://puppylinux.org/wikka/installationfrugal), I ran the universal installer and chose Harddisk,
Then i create a small partition with gparted (ext3, 1GB) and Puppy copied all the needed files from the Live-CD to the directory. In my case this was `/tmp/boot/...`

After that Puppy asks me to modify Grub `menu.lst`. Since I couldn't find it, I started installing by opening "grub config" program through the menu. All went smooth and I was asked to put the path where to install, and I used `/dev/sda1` since it's my hard drive.

After restarting i come to the grub boot manager where chosing Linux (on dev/sda1)
results in `Error 15: File not found`.

Is this path "TMP/boot/..." somehow wrong (Puppy 5.2 did put it there automatically)?

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are foolproof instructions to get it running 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxVOH3mo3Gw